# How are the research fields CSCW and HCI related historically?

Tags: hci, history

As part of writing my thesis, I was trying to reconstruct how exactly the research field of [Computer-Supported Cooperative Work (CSCW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-supported_cooperative_work) is related to [Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_interaction).

I have a decent understanding of the differences and overlap between the two, but was wondering to which degree they overlap historically. I presumed CSCW to have split off from HCI as a wider subject area since the field seemingly predates it, but have found no evidence in this regard. For example, the [wikipedia page on CSCW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-supported_cooperative_work) does not even mention HCI, whereas [that of HCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_interaction) merely mentions the overlap of which I am already aware.

A quick search (search for 'HCI') in a recent overview of CSCW by [Schmidt and Bannon (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10606-013-9193-7) does not even seem to mention a historical link between HCI and CSCW.

How exactly are the two related historically?

<sub>Schmidt, K., & Bannon, L. (2013). [Constructing CSCW: The first quarter century. Computer Supported Cooperative Work (CSCW)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10606-013-9193-7), 22(4-6), 345-372.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the CSCW paper you reference ([Schmidt & Bannon, 2013](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10606-013-9193-7)) does not seem to mention the historical relation between HCI and CSCW explicitely, it does reference an early *CHI paper* on the significance of CSCW by [Bannon (1992): Perspectives on CSCW: From HCI and CMC to CSCW](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247167107_Perspectives_on_CSCW_From_HCI_and_CMC_to_CSCW).

In chapter two of this paper (*"Issues in HCI"*) problems within HCI are discussed which have lead to the emergence of the CSCW field.

> In this Section, I concentrate  on  a  particular  area  of  research,
>   human-computer  interaction  (HCI)  and  argue  that the field has
>   been encountering a series of crises concerning the utility of its
>   conceptual approach and  empirical  methodology  over  the  last  few 
>   years<sup>1</sup>. Later  I  will  argue  that  the  shift  in
>   perspective  underlying  CSCW  research  can  be  seen  to  avoid  or 
>   reduce  the  severity  of  some  of these problems. While some argue
>   that CSCW is simply an "extension" of existing HCI research and 
>   development,  my  point  is  that    one  can  detect  a  switch  not 
>   simply  in  emphasis,  but  also  in conceptual frameworks, and even
>   methodologies, in the new research field.
>   ...
>   My  basic  thesis  is  that  this  mainstream  "cognitive  science"-inspired HCI  research  has  come  up  against  a  number  of  problems,  both  in  terms  of    its  research  agenda and the usability and utility of its empirical results for the software design community (Bannon, 1990,  1991)

Concluding from this I thus feel it can be said that CSCW split off from HCI when it first originated due to dissatisfaction with the major methods employed *at that time*.

<sub>Schmidt, K., & Bannon, L. (2013). [Constructing CSCW: The first quarter century. Computer Supported Cooperative Work (CSCW)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10606-013-9193-7), 22(4-6), 345-372.

Bannon, Liam J. (1992). [Perspectives on CSCW: From HCI and CMC to CSCW](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247167107_Perspectives_on_CSCW_From_HCI_and_CMC_to_CSCW), In EW-HCI’92:
Proceedings of the International Conference on Human-Computer Interaction, August 1992, St.
Petersburg, Russia, pp. 148–158.</sub>